# How to insert data from 1 view to 2 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I'm trying to insert a data from Checkout view to 2 tables in my database. Here is my CheckoutController:

```
 19 public function index()
 20 {
 21   $websites = Website::all();
 22   return view('checkout')->with([
 23       'websites' => $websites,
 24   ]);
 25 }
 26
 27 /**
 28 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 29 *
 30 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 31 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 32 */
 33 public function store(Request $request)
 34 {
 35   // Insert into orders table
 36   $data = Order::create([
 37       'user_id' => $request->user_id,
 38       'date' => $request->date,
 39       'order_number' => $request->order_number,
 40       'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
 41       'billing_subtotal' => $request->billing_subtotal,
 42       'billing_tax' => $request->billing_tax,
 43       'billing_total' => $request->billing_total,
 44   ]);
 45   $order = DB::table('orders')->insert($data);
 46
 47   //Insert into order_menu table
 48   foreach (Cart::content() as $item) {
 49       $cartitem = OrderMenu::create([
 50           'order_id' => $data->id,
 51           'menu_id' => $item->model->id,
 52           'quantity' => $item->qty,
 53       ]);
 54       $cart = DB::table('order_menu')->insert($cartitem);
 55   }
 56
 57   Cart::instance('default')->destroy();
 58   return redirect('status');
 59 }
```

And for the Checkout.blade.php :

```
 <form action="{{ route('checkout.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 100px">
        <div class="details">
            <div class="billing">
                <div class="cart-title"> Detail Pesanan </div>
                <hr>
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="user_id" class="form-label"> Meja </label>
                        <input type="text" value="{{ auth()->user()->name }}" class="form-control" disabled placeholder="{{ auth()->user()->name }}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="payment_method" class="form-label"> Payment </label>
                        <select name="payment_method" id="payment_method" class="form-control" required>
                            <option value="" style="font-size: 15px;"> Choose Payment... </option>
                            <option name="payment_method" value="Pay Now" style="font-size: 15px;"> Pay Now </option>
                            <option name="payment_method" value="Pay Later" style="font-size: 15px;"> Pay Later </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <input id="user_id" name="user_id" type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}" />
                    <input id="date" name="date" type="hidden" value="{{ date('d M Y', strtotime(today())) }}" />
                    <input id="order_number" name="order_number" type="hidden" value="{{ rand(1000,9999)}}{{ date('Ymd', strtotime(today())) }}" />
                    <input id="billing_subtotal" name="billing_subtotal" type="hidden" value="{{ Cart::subtotal() }}" />
                    <input id="billing_tax" name="billing_tax" type="hidden" value="{{ Cart::tax() }}" />
                    <input id="billing_total" name="billing_total" type="hidden" value="{{ Cart::total() }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="cart-buttons" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                <a href="{{ route('cart.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary" style="color: white;"> Kembali ke Keranjang </a>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="color: white; background-color: #BB4430"> Buat Pesanan </button>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cart">
            <div class="cart-title">
                Pesanan Anda
            </div>
            <div class="cart-table">
                <table class="table">
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (Cart::content() as $menu)
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <t style="font-weight: bold;"> {{ $menu->model->name }} </t>
                                <br>
                                <d style="color: #acacac;"> </d>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{ $menu->qty }}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: #acacac;"> Subtotal </td>
                            <td style="color: #acacac;"> Rp. {{ Cart::subtotal() }} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="color: #acacac;"> Pajak </td>
                            <td style="color: #acacac;"> Rp. {{ Cart::tax() }} </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Total </td>
                            <td> Rp. {{ Cart::total() }} </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But it only inserts data to order table and got this error:

"Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\mieaceh\app\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController.php on line 45"

And also for the date input, the data couldn't be inserted to the database table.

How do I solve this? I'm new to Laravel

Comment: Please add your full controller function here, including the function definition line. Also, if you could add your Form, it would be more helpful.

Comment: @aufa does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Model::create() function creates a new entry into the Table, you don't need to insert it a second time by `$order = DB::table('orders')->insert($data);` and
`$cart = DB::table('order_menu')->insert($cartitem);`. Plus the second time it's just the object returned by the previous insert that you are trying to insert into the table.

```
// Insert into orders table
    $data = Order::create([
        'user_id' => $request->user_id,
        'date' => date('Y-m-d', $request->date), // Edit 
        'order_number' => $request->order_number,
        'payment_method' => $request->payment_method,
        'billing_subtotal' => $request->billing_subtotal,
        'billing_tax' => $request->billing_tax,
        'billing_total' => $request->billing_total,
    ]);
    $order = DB::table('orders')->insert($data); // Remove this line

    //Insert into order_menu table
    foreach (Cart::content() as $item) {
        $cartitem = OrderMenu::create([
            'order_id' => $data->id,
            'menu_id' => $item->model->id,
            'quantity' => $item->qty,
        ]);
        $cart = DB::table('order_menu')->insert($cartitem); // Remove this line
    }

    Cart::instance('default')->destroy();
    return redirect('status');
```

Comment: This works, but what about the date input?

Comment: ```dd($request)``` do this before ```Order::create()``` and see if the date input is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'. If not, follow the edit I've made to my answer. @aufa

Comment: I did as you said but still it won't insert the date to the database